# std::bind2nd on an already bind1st std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to figure out how binders work. I am working on the example from [HERE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). So I decided to extend it a bit but I can't figure out what is wrong

```
namespace mine {
   using std::bind1st;
   using std::bind2nd;
   using std::function;
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};


int main()
{

using namespace mine;

    // store a call to a member function
    function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
    Foo foo(314159);
    f_add_display(foo, 1);

    function<void(int)> foo_f_add_display = bind1st(f_add_display, foo);
    foo_f_add_display(1);

    // The problem is here  <------------
    function<void(const Foo&)> f_1_add_display = bind2nd(f_add_display, 1);
    // f_1_add_display(foo);
}
```

The error message I am getting (from Intel CC, gdb is unintelligible)

```
Compilation finished with errors:
c++/4.7/backward/binders.h(160): error: invalid redeclaration of member function "std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(const _Operation::first_argument_type &) const [with _Operation=std::function<void (const Foo &, int)>]" (declared at line 154)
operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type& __x) const
^
detected during instantiation of class "std::binder2nd<_Operation> [with _Operation=std::function<void (const Foo &, int)>]" at line 41 of "source.cpp"

compilation aborted for source.cpp (code 2)
```

What exactly is the problem here. Why is not possible to bind the second argument? or is it just some syntax error or something?

Code is [HERE](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Hywls%240) if anyone needs it.

Comment: If you have `std::function` available, you should also have `std::bind` (both were added in C++11). `std::bind` is a *lot* more convenient.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can settle for std::bind. It seems better than both.

Comment: @AndyProwl what's up with the crazy struct above? (on your link):) I hope it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Aurora: lol sorry, I added more stuff than I wanted. I was just doing some tests and that thing was supposed to prove a theory I had - well it didn't. Here is the correct [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$143)